# How to build custom route by adding taxonomies to URL ? ex: www.demo.com/communities/palo-alto/

Tags: custom-post-types, multisite, url-rewriting, taxonomy, urls

I am trying to achieve this in WordPress, but no luck

Here '**/communities**' is custom Taxonomy of post type 'PAGE', '**/Palo-alto**' is term from communities taxonomy .

1. I want user first to click on communities which will show all communities in grid, URL should be **[www.demo.com/communities/](http://www.demo.com/communities/)**
2. then after he can select one community from list, ex he select 'Palo-alto' , then URL should be **[www.demo.com/community/palo-alto/](http://www.demo.com/community/palo-alto/)**

BASICALLY here each community has its own home page , linked by communities taxonomy , like 'Palo-alto' has its own home page, 'las-Vegas' has its own, I want to show home page of particular community

problem is that I don't want .php at end of URL just *[www.demo.com/community/palo-alto/](http://www.demo.com/community/palo-alto/)*

Extra : after solving this issue I also want to show 'gallery', 'events', 'downloads' for that particular community ex; *[www.demo.com/community/palo-alto/events](http://www.demo.com/community/palo-alto/events)* , *[www.demo.com/community/palo-alto/gallery](http://www.demo.com/community/palo-alto/gallery)*

Comment: You can set the permalink structure from the dashboard: settings - permalinks.

Comment: You should not answer your question if you do not have the solution, but you can post a comment on the answer, further more you should specify why the answer it is not good, and why you down-voted the answer.

Comment: May be your question is not fully understandable, you may study the wp-template hierarchy: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/ and understand the meaning of archive, and single pages.

Comment: sorry for that , im not used to stackoverflow,